# Classifying instances of a set with a Classification Model on WEKA GUI

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, svm, arff

I am new to data mining and I would like to ask you a classification question.
I have trained a classification algorithm on WEKA (GUI), using a training set in ARFF format. Consequently I saved it in Model format for future use.
Now I want to use this classification Model on WEKA (GUI) to get the predicted class of instances of a set that is also in ARFF format. Could you please give me instructions on how to do this on WEKA? Unlike the Weka Java API, the GUI version has really poor documentation in the Web and I couldn't find anything relevant.

Is it possible to store the classified set back to ARFF format with '?''s replaced with the class label in the class attribute? I need such outputs files for some computations.

Thank you beforehand.